# Is Firebase a good solution for this app?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm writing a mobile app which requires a backend that does the following things:

- user authentication (and prevent spamming accounts)
- allow users to fill out polls and vote yes/no on questions
- collect, aggregate, and serve "bulk data" from govtrack.org (caching results would be ideal, but if not I need a way to keep copies of this data and have them update daily)
- allow users to submit questions and favorite/upvote them
- track actions within the app for analytics (daily login, number of polls/votes submitted in a time period, anon location of users, etc)

Eventually, I would also like it to support:

- stream video/playback recording
- support chat/forum
- push notifications

A few people have recommended Google Firebase for this task, but I'm a little scared of the NoSQL data storage. Honestly, I've never even heard of it until today, and always worked with MySQL when I wrote backends for my previous apps. Is this a deal breaker for an analytic-heavy app like I'm planning to make? If in the future I ever decided to migrate to another backend, is it reasonably easy to convert the JSON into a relational database?

Comment: nosql will be quite tricky to master but it does have realtime database advantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes. Firebase is an excellent solution. However, you need to get familiar with the concept of NoSQL and how to structure your database there. If you are used to working with SQL than it might be a bit hard at first since it is so different. 
Also, if you app will need complex queries, like for example generating reports using multiple data sources - you might want to search for a different backend solution (it's not impossible but that sort of complex queries are better for SQL databases)